# Can a type conform to protocol with a higher access level that the type itself?

Tags: swift, access-control, swift-protocols

According to Apple's doc:

> “A type can conform to a protocol with a lower access level than the type itself. ”

However, the following piece of code could compile without error:

```
fileprivate class A : SomeProtocol {
    func foo() {}
}

public protocol SomeProtocol {
    func foo()
}
```

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: Are you written in both classes in the same file?

Comment: The fact that the code compiles doesn't contradict the statement you quoted – it says "can", not "can only". Apple are simply taking the fact that you can conform to a protocol with a higher access level for granted (as it makes perfect sense), and instead are focussing on the possibly more surprising case of conforming to a protocol with a lower access level.

Comment: @phanisai Yes, they are in the same file.

Comment: @hamish, Thanks for you comment! It looks to me that both the cases make sense, A type conforms to a protocol with a lower or higher access level. Thus i think it is a little bit weird that Apple's doc just mentions the first case and ignore the second.

Comment: @Hamish The doc makes sense to me now. Thanks for sharing your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Although Apple's doc doesn't mention it, a type actually can conform to a protocol with a higher access-level than the type itself.